# Eclipse and setting global jvm system properties i.e. -Dxxx=yyy

Tags: java, eclipse

I have lot of junits that depend upon the same jvm system props. Currently, I need to add these specifically for each of the junit's. The best I could do was to create a new VARIABLE and then reuse the variable across all these tests. Still, I need to specify this VARIABLE explicitly for each of the tests. Is there any way I can specify this at the eclipse level?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under `Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`. You can edit the JRE installation and set default VM arguments.